PySpark Production Container based best practices
I'm quite new to PySpark and was looking for some advice on how to kit production environments with docker.  I'm building an ML pipeline that continuously consumes events from Kafka.  I mention this in passing to emphasise that (a) there will be many dependencies for my main.py file and (b) the job will be running on the cluster at all times.  In digging around there seems to be quite a few options (couple mentioned below), but was looking for guidance on best practices.

Build the PySpark worker container images with the dependencies installed (pip install requirements.txt etc) then copy main.py in.
Tar the dependencies and run a spark-submit with the relevant files
Seems to be a spark-extension lib that can be used to load dependencies at run time
Airflow submitted method
I was also wondering whether it would be possible to mount a volume on the container and have the dependencies and main.py present on the docker host system

I quite like the last option, but haven't actually seen anyone implement it, which makes me think it may be a non-option.  Anyways ... experience and thoughts much appreciated.
This more a philosophy and experience question.

If the code and dependencies only exist on the host system, you're not really getting much benefit from Docker.  Use a plain-Python virtual environment instead.

By having the dependencies and code on the host system I could mount this into all the PySpark containers.  Then run the job against the PySpark cluster.  This way it would be easy to make any changes on the host code without re-kitting a new docker image with the changes.

Do you even need Docker for that workflow, though?

Ah, I think I see what you mean David.  You're saying just run the workflow on the host natively with a PySpark local instance?  That would work, however the overall solution is container based (the ML pipeline is just one small part of it's function) and I'd get put on the naughty step for inconsistency.  Also, I'd be losing options for distributing processing vertically across the datacentre.
